# set start point for bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

Hello I'm having a problem with my bootstrap dropdown every dropdown has to start where the first nav option is like in the pictures below. If you need some more info just tell me and i will add it to this post.

I've did some research already and I've seen some examples about mega menu stuff but i couldn't get it to work in my project so i started to do it my self.

[image]
[image]

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .Tilebackground {
    background-color: #efefef !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 145px !important;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
  }
  
  .Tileheader {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji';
    color: #414142;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 12.926px;
    transform: scale(1.259, 1.259);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .Tilefooter {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: #414142;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .mega-menu {
    width: 863px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  
  .dropdown-item {
    color: white !important;
  }
  
  .btn {
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  
  .btn-secondary {
    border-color: initial !important;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .relative {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #787878;">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="width: 100%; background-color: #787878; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Over Connect Pro</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Referenties</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Vacatures</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #FFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #787878;">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar" style="width: 100%; padding: 20px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: #000"><img src="images/toplogo.png" alt="Connect Pro"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" style="color: #000" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupported">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color: #000" ></span>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse relative" id="navbarSupported">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle Tilebackground" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <p class="Tileheader">Onze aanpak</p>
      <p class="Tilefooter">PROACTIEVE ICT <br> ONDERSTEUNING <br> VOOR BEDRIJVEN</p>
     </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu mega-menu w-100 absolute container" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <div class="row w-100 d-flex">
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">And an another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">one more action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">And an another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">one more action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">And an another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">one more action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle Tilebackground" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <p class="Tileheader">Oplossingen</p>
      <p class="Tilefooter">LOKALE INFRASTRUCTUUR,<br> CLOUD, VOIP, SECURITY, <br>TICKETING, MONITORING,...</p>
     </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu mega-menu w-100 absolute container" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
                <div class="row w-100">
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here2</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here2</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here2</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle Tilebackground" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <p class="Tileheader">Producten</p>
      <p class="Tilefooter">FIREWALLS, PRINTERS, <br> NOTEBOOKS, SIP PHONES, <br>EN MEER</p>
     </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu mega-menu w-100 absolute container" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton3">
                <div class="row w-100">
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here3</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here3</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here3</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle Tilebackground" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <p class="Tileheader">Partners</p>
      <p class="Tilefooter">ONS NETWERK VAN <br> LOKALE IT PARTNERS <br>OVER HEEL BELGIË</p>
     </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mega-menu container" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here4</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here4</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action4</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here4</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey man - just to be clear - when you hover on the first box the dropdown menu should be 4 blocks wide? what size should it be when you hover over the last box? for example how many "boxes" wide?

Comment: and also, where should the last box dropdown begin from? at the moment it starts from the 2nd from the end

Comment: @CodeBoyCode Yes every dropdown has to be 4 blocks wide and every dropdown should start at the left side of the " onze aanpak" block and end at the right side of the last block. I hope you understand what i just said :)

Comment: every dropdown should start and end like in the first picture @CodeBoyCode

Comment: There's a "script error" on the snippet.

Comment: @JerdineSabio i know but the page still works if you increase the result section

Comment: that makes sense - i will have a look at the problem - i may recommend adding something to highlight which box the user is hovering over, purely for the UX of the site

Comment: Thanks in advance man @CodeBoyCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick, slightly hacky fix, but one the only way I can think of using bootstrap.

As the first box dropdown is working fine this one is good. However for the other 3 boxes I have given them each a class (I used dd-2, dd-3 and dd-4).

All I did was set the `position: absolute;` `left:` figure to minus the width of the button (220px)

(added) CSS:

```
.dd-2 //dropdown box 2 {
    left: -220px;
}

.dd-3 //dropdown box 3 {
    left: -440px;
}

.dd-4 //dropdown box 4 {
    left: -660px;
}
```

here is my codepen showing how this was used (sorry I split your code up for my codepen) : https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/Pyyvgw

Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what if add a block in the future? Will this have an responsiveness issue for mobile users?, This is what i'm looking for

Comment: In that case you would need to work out the same calculation - obviously this is a solution without using JavaScript

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

"By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. Add .dropdown-menu-right to a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown menu.

Heads up! Dropdowns are positioned only with CSS and may need some additional styles for exact alignment."

Comment: would you be willing to accept this answer considering I have provided a fix and research to back up not being able to resolve this any other way?